# Testcontainers - DB context registered is always overridden by the program class DB context registration

Tags: .net, integration-testing, testcontainers

I am trying to create a mssql container using testcontainers-dotnet for my integration tests. I am able to spin up the container successfully in the docker using testcontainers-dotnet but when I try to apply the migrations it always points to the database that is registered in the program class even though I have overridden it using WebApplicationFactory's ConfigureWebHost method (inside ConfigureTestServices) I am not sure why this is being overriden. I am sure there must be something wrong that I am doing but I can't spot it.

Below is the code for my CustomApiFactory

```
public class CustomApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
    {
        protected readonly  MsSqlContainer _msSqlContainer;

        public CustomApiFactory()
        {

            _msSqlContainer = new
            MsSqlBuilder()
           .WithPassword("mypass")
           .Build();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
            {
                var connectionstring = GetConnectionString();
                servicesConfiguration.RemoveAll(typeof(PersonContext));
                servicesConfiguration.RemoveAll<PersonContext>();
                servicesConfiguration.AddDbContext<PersonContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionstring));
            });
        }

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            await _msSqlContainer.StartAsync();
            using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersonContext>();
            var conn = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
            var constring = conn.ConnectionString;
            await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();

        }

        public new async Task DisposeAsync() => await _msSqlContainer.DisposeAsync();

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return $"Server=127.0.0.1,{_msSqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(1433)};Database=PersonDb;User Id=sa;Password=mypass;TrustServerCertificate=True";
        }
    }
```

I tried looking at several examples and also the github source for the package but still can't spot it

Comment: What is `Services`?

Comment: Its a web application factory Services

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove DbContextOptions in the ConfigureTestServices
so I had to include this before I added context in the Integration test

```
servicesConfiguration.Remove(servicesConfiguration.SingleOrDefault(service => typeof(DbContextOptions<PersonContext>) == service.ServiceType));
```

Rest of the code was fine. I am now able to apply migration.

I followed the [guide located here](https://testcontainers.com/guides/testing-an-aspnet-core-web-app/)